# Grouped barplot with cut y axis

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a plot with grouped barplots and a cut y axis. However I don't seem to be able to get both. Using this data:

```
d = t(matrix( c(7,3,2,3,2,2,852,268,128,150,
              127,74,5140,1681,860,963,866,
              470,26419,8795,4521,5375,4514,2487),
            nrow=6, ncol=4 ))
colnames(d)=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
```

I can get the grouped barplots like:

```
barplot( d, beside = TRUE)
```

[image: Example]

I can then get the cut y-axis using:

```
# install.packages('plotrix', dependencies = TRUE)
require(plotrix)
gap.barplot( as.matrix(d), 
             beside = TRUE, 
             gap=c(9600,23400), 
             ytics=c(0,3000,6000,9000,24000,25200,26400) )
```

[image]

However, then I loose the grouping and the A, B, C... labeling. How can I get both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this manually. Like `barplot`, `?gap.barplot` returns *the center positions of the bars.* Use these to add the labels.

Using `space`  for spacing between groups as in regular `barplot` does not seem to work. We can use a row of NAs to hack a space.

```
d = t(matrix( c(7,3,2,3,2,2,852,268,128,150,
                                127,74,5140,1681,860,963,866,
                                470,26419,8795,4521,5375,4514,2487),
                            nrow=6, ncol=4 ))
colnames(d)=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

# add row of NAs for spacing
d=rbind(NA,d)

# install.packages('plotrix', dependencies = TRUE)
require(plotrix)

# create barplot and store returned value in 'a'
a = gap.barplot(as.matrix(d), 
                gap=c(9600,23400), 
                ytics=c(0,3000,6000,9000,24000,25200,26400),
                xaxt='n') # disable the default x-axis

# calculate mean x-position for each group, omitting the first row 
# first row (NAs) is only there for spacing between groups
aa = matrix(a, nrow=nrow(d))
xticks = colMeans(aa[2:nrow(d),])

# add axis labels at mean position
axis(1, at=xticks, lab=LETTERS[1:6])
```

Comment: Very nice, can we hack in spaces between the groups somehow too?

Comment: Yea turns out NA is plotted as just a space

Answer (score 4):

With the help of the answer by koekenbakker I came up with this at last:

```
# install.packages('plotrix', dependencies = TRUE)
require(plotrix)

d = t(matrix( c(7,3,2,3,2,2,852,268,128,150,
                127,74,5140,1681,860,963,866,
                470,26419,8795,4521,5375,4514,2487),
              nrow=6, ncol=4 ))

# Hack for grouping (leaves the extra space at the end)
e = as.vector(rbind(d, rep(NA, 6)))[1:29]

a = gap.barplot(ceiling(as.matrix(e/60)), 
                gap=c(160,390),
                col=rep(c(grey.colors(4), 1), 6),
                #space=rep(c(rep(0,3), 1), 6),
                ytics=c(0,50,100,150,400,420,440),
                xaxt='n') # disable the default x-axis

xticks=c(2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5)

# add axis labels at mean position
axis(1, at=xticks, LETTERS[1:6] )

legend("topright", LETTERS[7:10],
       bty="n",  
       fill=grey.colors(4))
```

[image]