# cut y axis ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to cut the y axis of my barplot in two parts. The cutoff should be 5000 in the y axis. I don't know how to deal with this in ggplot. I'm quite new and I would appreciate any help.
ggplot has a function for this or I should modify my data before ploting?

This is the barplot:
[image]

I would like to have a plot like this: [Grouped barplot with cut y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202245/grouped-barplot-with-cut-y-axis)

Thank you in advance,

Comment: i'm afraid you won't find a 'clean' way to do this with ggplot. You could work something out with facetting, all right, but won't look as nice as the link you posted.

Comment: Thanks @agenis, I'm still trying but I can't find the solution. Maybe is not possible with ggplot, no idea. :(