# Replicate thinkcell "cutout/breaks" in R chart

Tags: r, histogram, bar-chart, visualization

I have very sparse data and I want to adjust the chart so that I can show the amount of the positive event rather than it being a speck on the chart next to the negative class.

In thinkcell ( an excel and powerpoint add in), there is a cool feature where you can effectively "hide" a part of the frequency.  An example is here.
[image]

The squiggly lines are a cut off to change the scale.

The kind of data I am working with

```
a<-data.frame("Changed"=rep(0,900))
b<-data.frame("Changed"=rep(1,50))
example<-data.frame(Changed=rbind(a,b))
hist(example$Changed)
```

Any suggestions on how to do this or how to represent this?  I guess at worst I could change the limit of the chart and just label it to show the value in the base... but its not that pretty or obvious.

Appreciate any thoughts.
J

Comment: perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202245/grouped-barplot-with-cut-y-axis

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know this package existed.  Didn't know the right thing to search for.  Thanks for the tip.  If you want to post an answer, happy to mark it as correct

Comment: just +1 the question/answer in the link :)